# TableLayout - TableRows with the same layout_weight don't have the same height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to create a `TableLayout` with 3 columns and 4 rows and I need that all the rows have the same height.

I have tried many things, but the result is always the same. The third row,the one that only has two TextViews, always ends up being the row with less height.

[image]

This is the xml for the layout:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="7">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Tipo Venta"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/tipoVentaSpinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="7">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Tipo Pago"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/tipoPagoSpinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/clienteRow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="7">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Cliente"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/clienteTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"/>


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/rucRow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="7">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="RUC"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rucEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buscarClieImageButton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

The `TableLayout` described above is part of another layout, that's why specify a `layout_weight` of 4 for it.

Do you have any idea what is causing this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to set the height for each row otherwise it will be the height of the contents. Try match_parent for all elements in TR and set each TR to a fixed dp. Also ensure that elements in the TR don't have any unwanted top and bottom margins that cause it to increase the height.

Comment: Hi, why aren't you giving any feedback ? Is there still some issue left, If so kindly tell.

Comment: Sorry @ShreeKrishna I've got caught up with some stuff at work. TBH your solution was the only one that was close to what I want to achieve (it looks like all the rows are the same size, but I can't tell for sure) Could you please explain to me  how it works?

Comment: It's ok bro, But to explain about it, The `weightSum` attribute is given to the parent layout and the `layout_weight` attribute is given to it's child views to make certain match. Lets say if you have **4** in weightSum then you can give it's child either 2 & 2 OR, 1 &3 or overall 4 to the single child but the sum has to match the parents `weightSum`. If still issue or doubt left in your mind, you can freely tell. If not then I will be glad if you accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was glad because you've chosen me for helping. I think it's not showing the same height because there is no `Spinner` in third row. Default height of `Spinners` may be greater than `TextViews` and your third row is ended up with only two `TextViews`.

So you can do a little trick to visually show the same height of 3rd row as others by doing this

```
<TableLayout
  ...
  android:weightSum="4.5">
 <TableRow
   android:layout_weight="1">...</TableRow>
 <TableRow
   android:layout_weight="1">...</TableRow>
 <TableRow
   android:layout_weight="1.5">...</TableRow>
 <TableRow
   android:layout_weight="1">...</TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

If it exactly didn't fulfill your requirements then you can easily increase OR decrease the `weightsum` of `TableLayout` and give matching `layout_weight` attribute to the rows to make them look similar sizes. But I think the same above solution will work for you. Hope this helps you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all elements height of each row to wrap_content instead of match_parent.

Comment: Sorry, I've already tried that and the result is exactly the same :(

Comment: Maybe you can replace the TableLayout for a GridLayout. You will have to manage the layout positions programatically but I think you will avoid this difference to happen. If I have some time I will try to do a proto and upload it.